# como obtener el resultado correcto mediante el handlechange?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

El filtro de búsqueda tiene un comportamiento algo extraño que no logro averiguar el porque, cuando introduzco la provincia que deseo filtrar y presiono el botón de búsqueda que maneja la función handleChange recibo una respuesta incorrecta, pero al escribir de nuevo la provincia sin necesidad de presionar el botón de búsqueda me da la respuesta filtrada correctamente. Necesito recibir la provincia filtrada correctamente después de presionar el botón de búsqueda. Alguna idea de donde me estoy equivocando?

```
import React,  { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Clinic} from '@icofcv/common';
import Loader from '../spinner/Loader';



interface Props {
    showModalLocator: boolean,
    closeModalLocator: () => void
}


export const ClinicLocator: React.FC<Props> = ({ children, showModalLocator, closeModalLocator }) => {

    const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [clinicListFiltered, setClinicListFiltered] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [searchClinic, setSearchClinic] = useState("");

    const handleChange= (e) => {
        getClinic().then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            setClinicList(response);
            setClinicListFiltered(response)
            
            
        }).catch ( (error)  => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
            setSearchClinic(e.target.value);
            
      
      }

  
    useEffect(() => {
        if (searchClinic.length > 0) {
          const filterList = clinicList.filter((element) => element.province?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchClinic));
          setClinicListFiltered(filterList);
        } else {
            setClinicListFiltered(clinicList);
        }
      }, [searchClinic]);
  

    return (
        <>
              <div>
                {showModalLocator ? (
                    <>
                        <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
                            <div className="relative p-2 w-full max-w-3xl h-full md:h-auto">
                                {/*content*/}
                                <div className="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow">
                                    {/*header*/}
                                    <div className="flex justify-between items-start px-4 py-3 rounded-t border-b">
                                        <h3 className="text-lg font-medium">Localizador de clinicas</h3>
                                        <button className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center" onClick={closeModalLocator}>
                                            <svg aria-hidden="true" className="w-5 h-5" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                            </svg>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    {/*body*/}
                                    <div className="relative px-3 py-3 flex-auto overflow-auto modal-body">
                                        <h2 className="text-sm font-medium mb-2">¿Dónde te encuentras?</h2>
                                        <input 
                                        value={searchClinic}
                                        onChange={(e) => setSearchClinic(e.target.value)}
                                        type="search" 
                                        className="w-100 bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block p-2" 
                                        placeholder="Introduce una ubicación"
                                        />
                                        <div className="py-3 border-b flex flex-col md:flex-row items-start md:items-center md:justify-between justify-start gap-2">
                                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                                <label className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" className="sr-only peer" checked/>
                                                    <div className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer peer-focus:ring-teeal-600 
                                                    peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] 
                                                    after:absolute after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-teal-600"></div>
                                                    <span className="ml-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-900">Centro privado</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                                <label className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" className="sr-only peer" readOnly/>
                                                    <div className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer peer-focus:ring-teeal-600 
                                                    peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] 
                                                    after:absolute after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-teal-600"></div>
                                                    <span className="ml-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-900">con Mútuas</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                                <label className="inline-flex relative items-center mr-5 cursor-pointer">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" className="sr-only peer" readOnly/>
                                                    <div className="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 rounded-full peer peer-focus:ring-teeal-600 
                                                    peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] 
                                                    after:absolute after:top-0.5 after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-teal-600"></div>
                                                    <span className="ml-2 text-xs font-medium text-gray-900">con Compañías de Salud</span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>                                            
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <h2 className="text-sm font-medium my-3">Resultados</h2>
                                            <div className="w-100">
                                                <iframe className="w-100" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2664.3238269926374!2d-0.3805919350162851!3d39.46959682083709!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd604f4bee0957f3%3A0x6686ff7d230b3965!2zQy4gZGUgU2FudC
                                                BWaWNlbnQgTcOgcnRpciwgNjEsIHBpc28gMsK6LCBwdGEgMsKqLCA0NjAwMiBWYWzDqG5jaWEsIEVzcGHDsWE!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sus!4v1662388390673!5m2!1ses!2sus" loading="lazy"></iframe>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="md:mt-4 overflow-auto relative py-2">
                                                <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 gap-2">
                                                    <div className="card bg-white px-2 py-3 h-36 md:h-32">
                                                        {!clinicListFiltered ? <Loader /> :
                                                            clinicListFiltered.map((clinicFilter) => (
                                                        <button key={clinicFilter.id} type="button" className="text-left">
                                                            <div className="flex items-center gap-2 md:gap-4 md:gap-4">
                                                                <img className="h-24 w-2/5 min-w-40 object-cover object-center rounded-lg" src="../carousel-1.svg" alt="#"/>
                                                                <div className="w-3/5">
                                                                    <div className="text-md font-medium leading-5 clinic-title uppercase">{clinicFilter.title}</div>
                                                                    <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                                                                        <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinicFilter.propsPhone}</div>
                                                                        <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinicFilter.mobile}</div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div className="text-teal-600 text-sm underline clinic-mail">{clinicFilter.email}</div>
                                                                    <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">{clinicFilter.registry}</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </button>
                                                            ))
                                                        }
                                                    </div>
                                                    {/* <div className="card bg-white px-2 py-3 h-36 md:h-32">
                                                        <button type="button" className="text-left">
                                                            <div className="flex items-center gap-2 md:gap-4 md:gap-4">
                                                                <img className="h-24 w-2/5 min-w-40 object-cover object-center rounded-lg" src="../carousel-1.svg" alt="#"/>
                                                                <div className="w-3/5">
                                                                    <div className="text-md font-medium leading-5 clinic-title uppercase">AlamedaVLC</div>
                                                                    <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
                                                                        <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">963255652</div>
                                                                        <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">963255652</div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <div className="text-teal-600 text-sm underline clinic-mail">fisioalamedavlc@gmail.com</div>
                                                                    <div className="text-neutral-500 text-sm">9947</div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div> */}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    {/*footer*/}
                                    <div className="flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-2 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b gap-2">
                                        <button className="btn text-black text-sm background-transparent px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-teal-600 focus:border-teal-600" type="button" onClick={closeModalLocator}>Cancelar</button>
                                        <button className="btn bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white text-sm active:bg-teal-700 px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none" type="button" onClick={handleChange}>Buscar</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-black"></div>
                    </>
                ) : null}

            </div>

       </>
    )
}
```

Comment: podrias mostrar la logica de la funcion ´getClinic´, por otro lado, el archivo que estas mostrando contiene mucho codigo, te aconsejaria que lo simplifiques

Answer (score 0):

El error es que estas usando mal los eventos, si necesitas que la petición se realize al momento de dar click es necesario colocar el evento onClick en el boton se búsqueda, ahi ejecutas la acción, ahora si quieres hacerlo cuando deje de escribir en el input puedes hacerlo con un onChange pero para evitar peticiones cada cambio puedes usar un debouser, este ayudara a hacer la petición cuando el usuario deje de escribir por unos milisegundos.

Debouser dependencia: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-hook/debounce

Espero te haya ayudado amigo, si esa no es tu solución comparte mas información sobre esto, para poder ayudar. Saludos

Comment: tengo el onClick en el botón de búsqueda que maneja la función handleChange, pero su comportamiento es extraño, no devuelve la búsqueda de forma correcta